# Kohana модуль pagination правильный роутинг

Tags: pagination, kohana

Установил модуль пагинации, все отображается но прописаный неверный роутинг. Данный модуль хочу использовать в разных контроллерах(categories,users, products). Но возникла проблема с роутингом. Допустим если я нахожусь в контроллере users то ссылки отображаются: http://localhost/shop/admin/index/index/page2
а должно http://localhost/shop/admin/users/index/page2

bootstrap.php

```
Route::set('admin', 'admin(/<controller>(/<action>(/page<page>)(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
    'directory'  => 'admin',
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action'     => 'index',
));

Route::set('default', '(<controller>(/<action>(/page<page>)(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

Comment: не как не могу понять правила написания роутов. Вот у меня есть роут:
Route::set('catalog', 'catalog(/<action>(/c<cat>)(/<id>))')
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'index',
        'action' => 'index',
        'controller' => 'catalog',
    ));

http://localhost/shop/catalog/cat/c9

А как мне сделать вот та чтобы было:http://localhost/shop/catalog/cat/c9/page2

2.Подскажите где есть хорошое обьяснения по написанию роутов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::set('admin', 'shop/admin/users/(/page<page>)', array(
        'page' => '(\d+)',
    ))
    ->defaults(array(
        'directory' => 'admin',
        'controller' => 'index',
        'action' => 'index',
        'page' => ''
    ));
```

Как-то так?

UPD
Пропишите отдельные роуты на каждый путь.

```
Route::set('admin_users', 'admin(/users(/index(/page<page>)(/<id>)))')
   ->defaults(array( 
        'directory' => 'admin', 
        'controller' => 'index',//поправьте как у вас
        'action' => 'users',//поправьте как у вас 
)); 
Route::set('admin_categoryes', 'admin(/categoryes(/index(/page<page>)(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array( 
    'directory' => 'admin', 
    'controller' => 'index',//поправьте как у вас 
    'action' => 'categoryes',//поправьте как у вас 
));
В контроллерах, соответсявенно, необходимые action'ы:
action_users (){...}
action_categoryes(){...}
```

Comment: Не работает.

Comment: Извините, так вот :
....., 'shop/admin/users/index(/page<page>)'........

Comment: Все равно не верный роут.

Comment: Тогда прошу вас подробней объяснить что вы делаете, чего добиваетесь и при чём здесь пагинатор?

Comment: У меня есть административная часть сайта. Есть контроллер categories и users. В них есть методы в которых показыветься список всех категорий и список пользователей. Я хочу сделать разбиения на страницы. Пагинатор выводится но ссылки в нем не правильны. Допустим если я нахожусь в контроллере users то ссылки отображаются: http://localhost/shop/admin/index/index/page2 а должно http://localhost/shop/admin/users/index/page2
Тоже самое должно быть и в категориях только вместо users - categories.

Comment: Пропишите отдельные роуты на каждый путь.

Route::set('admin_users', 'admin(/users(/index(/page<page>)(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
    'directory'  => 'admin',
    'controller' => 'index',//поправьте как у вас
    'action'     => 'index',//поправьте как у вас
));
Route::set('admin_categoryes', 'admin(/categoryes(/index(/page<page>)(/<id>)))')
->defaults(array(
    'directory'  => 'admin',
    'controller' => 'index',//поправьте как у вас
    'action'     => 'index',//поправьте как у вас
));

Пагинатор не всегда корректно отрабатывает на обобщённых роутах.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста еще в написании роута. Хочу Сделать роут каталога товаров. Ссылки могу быть ввида: http://localhost/shop/catalog/cat/3
или же вот такого вида: http://localhost/shop/catalog/cat/3/product/12

Сам сделал следующие:
Route::set('catalog', '<cat>/<product>', array('cat' => '[-a-z0-9_]+', 'product' => '[-a-z0-9_]+'))
->defaults(array(
        'directory'  => 'index',
        'action' => 'index',
        'controller' => 'catalog',
    ));
Ну это будет роут без /catalog. Пробывал добавить вначало catalog но ошибка.

Comment: Route::set('catalog', 'catalog(/<cat_name>/(<product_id>))', array('cat_name' => '[-a-z0-9_]+', 'product_id' => '\d+')) ->defaults(array( 'directory' => 'index', 'controller' => 'catalog', 'action' => 'index', 'cat_name' => '', 'product_id' => '' ));

В контроллере получаете значения 

$product_id = (int)$this->request->param('product_id');
$cat_name = $this->request->param('cat_name');

Comment: А можно и так:
Route::set('catalog', 'catalog/<cat_name>/<product_id>', array('cat_name' => '[-a-z0-9_]+', 'product_id' => '\d+')) ->defaults(array( 'directory' => 'index', 'controller' => 'catalog', 'action' => 'product_view', 'cat_name' => '', 'product_id' => '' ));

Route::set('catalog', 'catalog/<cat_name>)', array('cat_name' => '[-a-z0-9_]+')) -> defaults(array( 'directory' => 'index', 'controller' => 'catalog', 'action' => 'cat_view', 'cat_name' => '', ));

Comment: Route::set('catalog', 'catalog') -> defaults(array( 'directory' => 'index', 'controller' => 'catalog', 'action' => 'cats_view', ));

Т.е. 3 роута на каждое действие. Так, ИМХО, логичнее, чем в самом контроллере определять что показывать - список категорий, содержимое категории или саму статью.